# Computing shear strain in a discrete domain

Tags: civil-engineering, modeling

i am doing a uniaxial test on a body and the body(2D) is discretized to a number of points(x,y)and is assumed to be elastic. the node size is $\Delta x = \Delta y$. Let us assume that force is applied in x-direction(tensile) and value of force/elasticity is a 0.001.
I believe that the displacement on the body is given by $ displacement_x = 0.001 * x$ and $displacement_y = -poisson's ratio * 0.001 * y$. The strain at any point in x-direction is 0.001 which remains constant and the strain along y-direction also remains constant at a value of -0.001 * poisson's ratio.
How do i show that the shear strian is zero in this case. i want to show that using the displacement values computed and not like this $\gamma_{xy}$ = $\tau / G = 0$, since $\tau = 0$ or showing $\partial u/ \partial y = 0, \partial v / \partial x = 0$. Please use finite difference approximations.

Comment: In an isotropic material, shear strain is uncoupled to normal stress. Is your material isotropic?

Answer (score 0):

Shear strain corresponds to a change in shape—to angles changing. If the normal strains are uniform, then all points remain connected by vertical and horizontal lines, and every angle remains 90°. So the shear strain is zero.